# Glade alternative for Quickly?

Tags: software-recommendation, application-development, quickly, glade

Is there? I am not getting on with Glade one bit. Any other ones out there that are better to use? Thing I dont like about Glade is when I make a mistake and I save I cannot undo along with several other issues.

Comment: Any ideas? 5 more to go.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of an alternative; the alternative is to construct your interfaces in code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use glade for my own projects, I find it too limiting and dislike having to switch between my text editor and a GUI program.  Also, while glade does take care of a lot of simple drudgery, you're still going to have to do the harder bits in code anyway, so why not do it all in code?

I'll generally define functions to take care of constructing frequently used widgets, like labels, buttons, and menu items.  This also helps me enforce a common style across all the widgets.

There are frameworks and toolkits out there, like Kiwi and quidgets, that aim to give you higher level abstractions, but personally I find them either way overkill or not exactly what I need, so I just use them for ideas and make my own custom widget code.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use PyQt instead.

http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro